# How to prove absolute summabilities implies the absolute summability of the product series?

Tags: convergence, sum

In SHUMWAY 2017 Time Series Analysis and Its Applications with R examples 4E, page 486, it states:

$\Sigma_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_j| < \infty$ and $\Sigma_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |b_j| < \infty$ implies $\Sigma_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_j b_j| < \infty$.

How to prove this?

How to proceed from the following (if it is the correct starting)?:

$\Sigma_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_j b_j| = lim_ngoes\infty \Sigma_{j=-n}^{n} |a_j b_j|\leq;lim_ngoes\infty \Sigma_{j=-n}^{n} |a_j|| b_j|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely formal, but I think it simply follows from:$$\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |a_jb_j|=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |a_j||b_j|\leq \left(\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_j|\right)\left(\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|b_j|\right)$$

Comment: +1 It's close enough to formal.  For complete rigor you would need to change the summation limits to go from $m$ to $n$ and sprinkle lots of "$\lim_{m\to-\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}$" expressions throughout.  Note, too, that this is an easy consequence of Holder's Inequality with $p=1,q=\infty$ (after bounding one of the sums below by the maximum size of a single component).